# angularjs date filter not formatting my json value

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that returns json like so:

```
"Results":[{"Id":"1","SomeDate":"2/19/2013 10:34:04 PM"}
```

When i try to format using binding, it doesnt work - it just displays the string above:

```
{{values.SomeDate| date:'mediumTime' }}
```

However, it works if i just pass in this format:

```
{{ '1997-03-01T00:00:00+01:00' | date:'mediumTime'}}
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: docs define date formats, pass a valid format from server or create custom filter that parses your data to a valid date  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the comments by charlietfl, a clean option would be to update the service to return a date format already compatible with the built-in angular filters.

However, if this is not possible, you could set up a custom filter to parse your dates.

A (very small) library that I recommend is Moment.js:
http://momentjs.com/

The following is an example blog post on how to wrap Moment.js in a custom angular filter:
http://www.34m0.com/2012/07/angularjs-user-friendly-date-display.html

```
angular.module('myModule').
    filter('fromNow', function() {
        return function(dateString) {
            return moment(new Date(dateString)).fromNow()
        };
    });
```

This would be used like:

```
{{ reply.createdDate | fromNow }}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can place this in your controller:

```
  $scope.toJsDate = function(str){
    if(!str)return null;
    return new Date(str);
  }
```

and then:

```
{{toJsDate(values.SomeDate)| date:'mediumTime' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would second @AlexOsborn's suggestion to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to create a custom filter because moment.js can parse the string containing the date. In my implementation of the filter, I also delegate date formatting to moment.js because I feel moment.js' date formatting feature is [more comprehensive](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) than angular.js':

```
angular
.module("YourModuleNameHere")
.filter("formatdate", [function () {
    var result = function (date, formatstring) {
        if(formatstring === null) {
            formatstring = "DD MMM YYYY";
        }
        return moment(date).format(formatstring);
    }
    return result;
}]);
```

And you use it just like you'd use angular.js date filter (but to format the date you'd use moment.js formatting codes):

```
<p>Today is {{moment() | formatdate}}</p>
<p>Another date: {{values.SomeDate | formatdate:"ddd D MMM YYYY"}}</p>
```